# Trace of matrix equals sum of eigenvalues, pitfalls?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In this excercise I have the following stochastic matrix:
$$
A =\left(
 \begin{matrix}
  .3 & .6 \\
  .7 & .4 
 \end{matrix}
\right)
$$

I have been given one eigenvalue, $\lambda_1 = 1$.
Is it safe to assume that because $Tr(A) = .7$ 
the last eigenvalue must be $\lambda_2 = Tr(A) - \lambda_1 = -.3$?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine.

Comment: You can always use the fact that sum of eigenvalues is trace and the product is determinant. $A=C^{-1}\Lambda C$ where $\det C \neq 0$, $\Lambda$ is matrix with eigenvalues of $A$ on the main diagonal and zeros elsewhere, so clearly trace of $\Lambda$ is sum of eigenvalues of $A$ and since it's diagonal matrix it's determinant is just product of entries on the diagonal, and it's easy to check that $A$ and $\Lambda$ have equal traces and determinants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is always true. You could equally well use that the determinant is the product.

Answer (score 3):

Given that $\lambda =1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, you can assume the characteristic equation to be of the form

$$
p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)
$$

where $\lambda_2$ is the second eigenvalue

expanding

$$
p(\lambda)=\lambda^2-(1+\lambda_2)\lambda+\lambda_2
$$
and we know that

$$
p(\lambda)=\lambda^2-Tr(A)\lambda+\det(A)
$$
I now set

$$
Tr(A) = 1+\lambda_2=.7
$$

$$
\lambda_2=-.3
$$

I agree with your reasoning.